# Special string operate different in Class and in console

Tags: python, utf-8, encode

I input

```
config = {}
config['x'] = ["vision","unknown","SCH-i569","harmony","中国移动"]
```

is ok. The python console can handle it

But when I write the same code in a class init function,it occurs some encode problems

```
class Profile(object):
def __init__(self):
    attributes = []
    attributes.append('8')
    attributes.append('htc')
    config = {}
    config['x'] = ["vision","unknown","SCH-i569","harmony","中国移动"]
    print config['x']
    attributes.append(config['x'])
    self.attributes = attributes
def getAttributes(self):
    return self.attributes
```

it occurs a problem:

```
File "<stdin>", line 7
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd6 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

when I delete the `"中国移动"`, the class work. I don't know why it is different between a class  and other

Answer (score 2):

Add `#-*-coding:utf-8-*-` to your source file.

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/